# Float divs around a 'static'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a website with content in small divs. They are all floating left so basically it's all tiled. I want a banner every third row. How many content divs are visible depends on the users screen width. I had a solution in JavaScript, but IE doesn't like that.

More graphic: this is what I want:

[image: narrow screen]

and on a wider screen things should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I can't see there being a css solution to this problem. What's your solution in Javascript? How does it not work in IE?

Comment: Can you add container div for your small boxes and then find height of  that container div using jQuery and then put add banner dynamically.

Comment: So, what is the problem? The whole thing or just parts of it?

Comment: the JavaScript is way too slow for IE. Works great in Firefox. Basically what it does is check through each of the content divs using jQuery, then if the position.top changes for the 3rd time I prepend the advertising div in front of it. I'm re-calling this when the width of the site is changed, which is where the problem starts. I made sure the code is only executed for the 2nd when the height of the wrapping div is changed, so when the screen width is altered without it leaving room for more divs in a row nothing is executed

Comment: @dev, so that's basically what you suggested, right?

Comment: yes, but this needs good practice of JS/jQuery.

Comment: what would be great is to have DIV's that are connected in the background (like Adobe InDesign does with text windows), when the first block is filled it continues in the second. Maybe something for HTML 6 hey? ;-)

Comment: @dev, jQuery is not a problem

Comment: well i'd like to know how the content is created on the screen. if it is in the html, jquery (or similar) is probably the best bet (as @patrick noted: the divs are not connected, thus when the width is too small, content can only be hidden, not transfered with only css). however, with php this would be very, very easy.

Comment: it's not in PHP. Also, what it's used for is to keep a nice layout when the page is resized.

Comment: You're wasting your time looking for non-JS solutions. I tagged this as a `javascript` question for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Yqy9B/5/embedded/result/

```
<div class="row clear">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="row clear">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="advert">
    Advertisement
</div>

.row {
    height:80px; /*height = 10px margin(top/bottom) + 60px height of .box */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
    width:160px;
    height:60px;
    float:left;
    background:#999;
    margin:10px;
    display:inline;
}

.advert {
    width:485px;
    height:60px;
    margin:10px auto;
    background:red;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:60px;
}

.clear:before, .clear:after { content:""; display:table; }
.clear:after { clear:both; }
.clear { zoom:1; }  /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
```

Is that what you are talking about?
http://jsfiddle.net/Yqy9B/5/

Comment: Looks very promising! But unfortunately all blocks have content that needs to be visible... check http://jsfiddle.net/Yqy9B/6/, I put numbers in there. Right now numbers are skipped on a narrow screen.

Comment: Hmm, how many blocks per row do you need? And is this a fluid? Or a fixed layout? Or a combination of both?

I'm thinking of the possibility of a grid layout to be the answer to this, perhaps.

Comment: I want as many blocks as fit. and I want an add every 3 rows. So it's indeed a combination of fixed and fluid layout. I have it running now in all browsers, using some timer fixes found on stackoverflow, but I'm still wondering if there isn't a non-scripting solution to this. Would be a lot faster

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
For the overlapping issue in Chrome and Safari, I've added some code that will add some padding for those browsers, as I could not find a more elegant cross-browser solution. To see the version with the additional code, see http://jsfiddle.net/Yqy9B/16/. I've also updated the code below.

---

Using a combination of `clear:` and `float:` properties in CSS, we can space the advertisements down one side and the content down the other. This will allow for the content to flow around the advertisements, which will keep the ads in the same spot on resize, but flow the content boxes below it.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cjyoung1/Yqy9B/10/ (**update:** new example to address overlap: http://jsfiddle.net/Yqy9B/16/)

(*Note*: I left the spacer as red to show how it works, you can change it to your background color or transparent - but needs to be at least 1px wide to work properly in some browsers)

The CSS:

```
.box {
    width:160px;
    height:60px;
    margin:10px;
    background:#999;
    display:inline-block;
}

.advert {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    margin:10px auto;
    background:red;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:60px;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}

.spacer { 
    float:right; 
    clear: right; 
    height: 250px; 
    width: 1px; 
    background: #f00;
}

/* **Below are the updates to fix the overlap in other browsers** */
/* fix webkit overlap */ 
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    .advert{
        margin-top:80px;
    }
    .spacer{
        margin-bottom:-80px;     
    }
}

/* fix IE6 overlap */
* html .advert {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<!-- floating to right -->
<span class="spacer"></span>
<span class="advert">Advertisement</span>
<span class="spacer"></span>
<span class="advert">Advertisement</span>

<!-- floating to left -->   
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>
<div class="box">7</div>
<div class="box">8</div>
<div class="box">9</div>
<div class="box">10</div>
<div class="box">11</div>
<div class="box">12</div>
<div class="box">14</div>
<div class="box">15</div>
<div class="box">16</div>
<div class="box">17</div>
<div class="box">18</div>
<div class="box">19</div>
<div class="box">20</div>
<div class="box">21</div>
<div class="box">22</div>
<div class="box">23</div>
<div class="box">24</div>
<div class="box">25</div>
```

Comment: I checked the fiddle you posted, but the ads show up under the boxes now, would you know of a way the boxes don't show where the banners are?

Comment: Looks like I didn't test the code in enough browsers - seemed to work in IE8, IE9 and FireFox, but the webkit browsers and IE6 seem to have this overlap issue. For now, I've put together this example http://jsfiddle.net/Yqy9B/16/ that seems to work for the webkit/IE6 browsers too, but relies on a CSS trick to display differently for the browsers. I'm going to do some more research and see if there's a more elegant way to do this - if I find anything, I'll let you know.

Comment: that looks very promising Chris!

Comment: @patrick - Just wanted to let you know that I haven't forgotten about you. I've been looking for a method that didn't involve specific CSS for the different browsers, but it looks like this is the best I could do. If you play with the sizing and spacing, you can probably get it to look the way you'd like. Hope this helps!